# How to filter Groovy/Grails closure from web app

Tags: grails

I have a web app that makes a call to a grails app for its db calls.  The db is filled with products that are returned through groovy calls.  An example object that I would get from the db is as follows:

```
class Product{
    Boolean is_blue;
    Boolean is_round;
    Boolean is_alive;
    Boolean is_active;
    String type;
    String name;
}
```

I want to make a call to the grails app to filter on these boolean values but I am not sure how to do it via a closure, this what my closure currently looks like.

```
def productXML = 
     Product.findAll("from Product as p where p.is_active = 1 and p.type = :type 
                      ORDER BY p.${params.sort} ${params.order}", 
                      [type: type], [max: params.max, offset: params.offset])
```

What I'm most confused on is how I can pass these parameters to the closure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a query builder where if in in the query string it had is_blue=1,  I would add that to the query.

```
    if(params.is_blue){
        query +=" and p.is_blue = ${params.is_blue}"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
def productXML = 
     Product.findAll("from Product as p where p.is_active is :active \
                      and p.type = :type \
                      ORDER BY p.${params.sort} ${params.order}", 
                      [type: type, active: true], 
                      [max: params.max, offset: params.offset])
```

OR

```
def productXML = Product.findAll(params){
    type == type && is_active == active
}
```

is what you are looking for? Refer [findAll](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html) for details.

Comment: I am trying the second method and no matter what params try use, I am getting back all the results.

Comment: On the first method, it is complaining about the parameters being supplied.  I don't know what parameters I will be recieving from the client. for instance, sometimes the client will supply is_active but will not supply type.

Answer (score 0):

1. Always use substitution variables
2. To make parameters optional, use this trick (using type as an example):

def productXML = Product.findAll("from Product as p where p.is_active is :active 
and **(p.type = :type or :type == null)** 
ORDER BY p.:sort :order", 
[type: type, active: true, sort:params.sort, order:params.order], [max: params.max, offset: params.offset])